# Fix alignment of auto-complete box for @mentions

Tags: feature-request, autocomplete

This was hard to search for, so I apologize in advance if it is a duplicate.

Currently, the Auto-complete box for the @mentions is at the extreme left of the comment box.  This is great if you are typing

[image]

But not if you are typing:

[image]

What are the chances we can have the alignment match up with the inline text?

Comment: Not sure I'm a fan of this. Where would you show it when you're somewhere on the second line of the comment box? And why does it even matter where it is? And what if you type `@J` on the far right of the box, and there are four commenters starting with that letter?

Comment: @balpha - I think as long as it aligns horizontally it should be fine.  It's counter-intuitive to me to have it at the far left if I'm writing the name at the right.  I didn't even notice it initially and thought it wasn't appearing.